# Scaled percentage calculator - specific percentages for different number outcomes

Tags: google-sheets, formula, payment, percentage, conditional-formatting

We are a group based fitness studio working on a sheet that gives information on expenses and profits, most of the sheet is pretty straight forward, however, we want the sheet to calculate the royalty the investor should get but it is calculated on a sliding percentage calculator, i.e

0 - 199 members - 10% of gross revenue
200 - 299 Members - 12% of gross revenue
300 - 399 Members - 14% of gross revenue
400 - 499 Members - 16% of gross revenue
500+ members - 18% of gross revenue

The desired outcome is to produce a sheet that automatically switches the calculation from one percentage to another once the member number goes to the next member bracket (as stated above).

Obviously we could have a sheet that has multiple calculations to work this out but ideally, we want it worked out in the one cell to make it easier for an individual to understand.

I have added a link to the sheet below so you can see what we are looking to achieve

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E9_42vNvZgf_TmzJgX3MlNZO57SjriU7GZT6HTF6rAo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `LOOKUP`:

```
=LOOKUP(B3,{0,199,299,399,499},{0.1,0.12,0.14,0.16,0.18})
```

[image]

Comment: This was used in another work document we have, thank you for putting this forward.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is a sequence of nested IFs at a (possibly hidden) cell that will be the multiplication factor. This cell will have its value dynamically adjusted based on values of other cells. You can nest multiple IFs to check for intermediate/multiple conditions, for example:

```
// Single-check IF:
// Syntax: IF(condition;result;else)
=IF(B3>299;0.14;0.12)

// Nested IF:
=IF(B3>299;0.14;IF(B3>199;0.12;0.1))
```

Check it: [Dynamic Factor Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ksUdySD0Z1nvzL4J0pP7XMPRtdWL7ES1aHE_KuJXqJQ/edit?usp=sharing)